# How generate new deposit Tether address in Binance

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, binance

How can Generate new unique USDT (Tether) addresses for the deposit (for each order I need a new deposits address) in Binance API?

Comment: Did you found out if is it possible and how? I'm running into the same situation

Answer (score 2):

Only one address per currency per user may be generated. If you already have an address for a currency, you will not be able to generate a new address.

You can reach out to Customer Service if you’d like to change the deposit address manually.